# CallableStatement, named paremeters and order of binding

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, callable-statement

I'm using a CallableStatement to execute a SQL query with named parameters, and I'm getting different results depending on the order in which I bind the parameters. Here's my full test:

```
public void test() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
    ds.setUser("abcd");
    ds.setPassword("a");
    ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@efgh:1521:orcl");
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
    CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("select :a col_a, :b col_b from dual");
    stmt.setObject(":b", "b");
    stmt.setObject(":a", "a");
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
    resultSet.next();

    Assert.assertEquals("a", resultSet.getObject("col_a"));
    Assert.assertEquals("b", resultSet.getObject("col_b"));

}
```

It fails because col_a contains "b", and col_b contains "a". If I switch the two calls to `stmt.setObject` to make them in the order the variables appear in the query, then it works.

I've also tried:

- using setString/getString instead of setObject/getObject
- referencing columns by their index (`resultSet.getObject(1)` for col_a and `2` for col_b)
- combining both: `resultSet.getString(resultSet.findColumn("col_a"))`

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong, or of any other way I could be doing this?
I can't do with positioned parameters (with `?`) in PreparedStatement, as I can get different queries with the same parameters in different order.

For instance, I could get those two queries to execute:

- `select nvl(foo, :a), :b || something from my_table`
- `select decode(:b, 'b', aaa, ccc), eee || :a from another_table`

The statements have nothing in common except the presence of the variables `:a` and `:b`. But they are not in the same order, which means I cannot replace them with `?` and then use a PreparedStatement with variables binding with `stmt.setObject(1, a); stmt.setObject(2, b);`, because it would work for the first one, but not for the second.

In case it's useful, I'm using ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0, and the database is also in 11.2.0.2.0.

Comment: `CallableStatement` is meant to execute stored procedures, not issue simple `select` statements.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Can you please explain more about what you mean by " I can't do with positioned parameters (with ?) in PreparedStatement, as I can get different queries with the same parameters in different order." Also I don't really get the "select :a col_a, :b col_b from dual" query. Can you give another example: real table and real select.

Comment: Added an example in the question.

Comment: [Spring JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) provides support for named parameters. Regular JDBC does not.

Comment: Hi, actually it seems like bug. I had a problem yesterday. The order of named parameters should be the same as in query.